# GetObject("winmgmts:... crashes Excel 2016 with no Errors

Tags: excel, vba, wmi, excel-2016, windows-server

I am debugging some VBA code I've written in Excel 2016, and this sub is crashing Excel 2016 on windows Server with no errors.

It is crashing on the `Set RegObj = GetObject...`

```vb
Sub TestPrinter()
    On Error GoTo e
    Dim RegObj As Object
    'This next line is where the crash occurs...
    Set RegObj = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
Exit Sub
e:
    MsgBox "Error number " & Err & " in TestPrinter" & vbCrLf & "Error: " & Error$(Err)
End Sub
```

My end goal is to enumerate the printers connected on the machine, and then set `Application.ActivePrinter` based on the string I pull out of the registry. This code is working fine on every other machine I've tried it on - but fails on this one server.

How can I go about debugging this? The error handler is never hit.

Comment: You're intending to utilize `SWbemSecurity` or `winmgmts` to access `impersonationLevel`?  I have only seen the prior, so grain of salt.  I can only imagine you're interfacing with the service host and causing a necessary process to die.

Comment: @Cyril thank you for the comment. I'm not sure I'm understanding - can you explain a little more simply? This code is pulled out of a Sub I wrote to find a printer by name, and then get it's info from the registry so I can set Application.ActivePrinter

Comment: Take a look at [`SWbemSecurity.ImpersonationLevel property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemsecurity-impersonationlevel).  You essentially use the code designated as "You can also specify impersonation levels as part of a moniker. The following example sets the authentication level and the impersonation level, and retrieves an instance of Win32_Service", which may explain the issue as you're not just reading.  Again, I have only seen this done, not written the code myself, whereas the object being modified is a security object.  I apologize that I cannot add more.

Comment: Only a thought ... could you be running foul of the [Antimalware Scan Interface](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/malicious-macros-were-found-9e461c61-69d1-4ea9-a386-9ad0deaccfdd) ... try setting the folder that the Excel workbook is in as a Trusted Location?

Comment: @JohnM that's a good thought, thank you. I am not getting any antimalware dialog in Windows, so I don't know if that is it, but I will set the folder to a trusted location when I'm able to test again and see if that changes things.

Comment: You are running Office on a Windows Server?!?!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not answer your question but rather provides an alternative solution to setting the active printer.

You can use something like this to get the printer names:

```
Public Function GetPrinterNames() As Collection
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    With CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        For i = 1 To .EnumPrinterConnections.Count Step 2
            coll.Add .EnumPrinterConnections(i)
        Next
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set GetPrinterNames = coll
End Function
```

Note that the above does NOT give you the port number but that is not really necessary as you could use something like this to set the printer:

```
'*******************************************************************************
'Sets the ActivePrinter without requiring the winspool port number
'*******************************************************************************
Public Function SetPrinter(ByVal printerName As String) As Boolean
    If LenB(printerName) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Dim i As Long
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ActivePrinter = printerName
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        SetPrinter = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    Err.Clear
    For i = 0 To 99
        Application.ActivePrinter = printerName & " on NE" & Format$(i, "00:")
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            SetPrinter = True
            Exit Function
        End If
        Err.Clear
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. I will implement this and will mark it as the answer once I verify it solves my issue. Thank you!